# Is Azoun V King in Cormyr?

Tags: forgotten-realms

After the novel *Death of a Dragon* Cormyr is in tatters.

The Steel Princess is made Regent.

However many, many years have passed since I read any of the books concerning this wonderful kingdom.

Is the Obarskyr line still alive and well or did some other "bastard" od Azoun IV claim the throne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, the Obarskyrs continued to rule Cormyr.

[Azoun V](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Azoun_V) took the throne after the Steel Princess.  He was the son of Tanalasta (Azoun IV's daughter), detailed in *Elminster's Daughter*.  After Azoun V, his son Foril took the crown (in 1449, as detailed in “Backdrop: Cormyr”. Dragon #365 p. 49.).

> By 1486 Foril's son Irvil, who was king for a short tenure, has died and there were plans to crown Queen Raedra Obarskyr, as described in *Brimstone Angels: Fire In the Blood.*  That is the latest news I have.

[image: Fire in the Blood cover, woman in a dress wielding a staff]

So, to answer your question, the Obaskyr line has continued to rule over Cormyr (even through a civil war for the throne, during the time of Azoun V and Foril) for as long as our present crop of books run.