# What is the correct reading order of books for the Obarskyr line?

Tags: suggested-order, forgotten-realms

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129332/is-azoun-v-king-in-cormyr/129361#129361) question I found our that the line of Kings in Cormyr is still unbroken. What is the correct reading order of books if I'm only interested in catching up with the royal line of Cormyr?
The last book I read was *Death of a Dragon*.